# Maximum call stack size exceeded with overriding object's clone property JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, clone, prototype, this

Here is my function which I am using to override the `clone` property of an object to create a new copy of the object not only the reference.

```
Object.prototype.clone = function () {
    var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
    for (i in this)
    {
        if (i == 'clone') continue;
        if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
            newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
        } else
            newObj[i] = this[i]
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

I have also added few properties to the `window object`.

**Edit**

Actually I am using seeveral libraries in my code. When I run this method without these libraries, it works fine. But with these libraries it gives this error. It is possible they have provided their own implementation of clone.

Now when I call this method I get the `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Any Help?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a circular reference somewhere in the object you are cloning?

Comment: Because `clone` itself now will be recursively cloned... Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) before you move on.

Comment: @Passerby no, that's not the problem!

Comment: this seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/48syJ/

Comment: @mihai try to clone an empty array

Comment: @StefanHaustein: Actually I am using seeveral libraries in my code. When I run this method without these libraries, it works fine. But with these libraries it gives this error. It is possible they have provided their own implementation of clone.

Comment: @StefanHaustein: I think I have a circular reference with the `this` keyword, which I cannot change.

Comment: I'd add a console log statement to see where exactly the circle stems from. To check if any particular object has "suspicious" properties (that clone would see) I used Object.prototype.lp = function() { for (var p in this) {console.log(p);}}

Comment: @StefanHaustein: I found the reason for the error. Actually the `window` object was causing the problem because the clone property was being applied to that also and since the all the objects were insied the `window` object so, I think that was creating the circular path and causing the problem.
Thanks for your help and suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Trying your method on a normal `Object {}` works fine, the issue comes when used with an `Array []`

I am not completely sure this is what you are looking for, but it solved the problem:

```
Object.prototype.clone = function () {
    if (this instanceof Array) return this.slice(0);
    var newObj = {};
    for (var i in this) {
        if (i == 'clone') continue;
        if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
            newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
        } else newObj[i] = this[i];
    }
    return newObj;
};
```

If your `Object` is an instance of `Array` then cloning it in that way is not necessary, and I believe you can return it and stop the function. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzZCY/2/).

Comment: Arrays are also passed by reference, so it's still worth to copy: http://jsfiddle.net/nzZCY/1/

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work for me. Still giving the same error.

Comment: @Passerby you're right, I edited it, with `.slice(0)` works like a charm.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav yes it is possible that is a problem of conflicting code, we can't do so much with that type of issue...

Comment: @LightStyle `.slice(0)` still have pitfalls: http://jsfiddle.net/nzZCY/3/ Object copying in JS is simply messy.

Comment: @LightStyle Check out the fiddle carefully. I logged `b`, tempered (special part of) `a`, logged `b` again, and `b` is also tempered.

Comment: @LightStyle: I fixed the problem by making one change in my code. Actually somehow the `clone` method was being applied to the `window` object also. So I put a check for not not including the `window` object and it worked.
Thanks to all for all your help.

Comment: Btw: The main issue with slice here is that it doesn't apply clone to the contents of the array.